# How to read input as array and use it as variable in shell script?

Tags: bash, pdf, imagemagick, sh

I have created a shell script for creating thumbnail from PDF using ImageMagick. It will guide you step by step and then create a thumbnail based on your input.

Now I'm trying to remake "$page" part, cause you can use only one page (number) as input at the time.. And I want script to be able to read more page inputs at once (numbers separated by comma or space) - save them to an array, and then use this array as variable ($page) in "CONVERT" function...

Anybody have an idea?

Thank you!

Here's the code:

```
    # set function
CONVERT()
{
    num=0
    name=$(basename "$file" .pdf | cut -d- -f1 | sed 's/.$//' | tr ' ' '-')
    ext="png"
    mark='/path/to/the/watermark.png'
    if [[ ! -e "$path"/"$name"_$num.$ext ]]; then
        echo "Creating thumbnail ..."
        convert -quiet -density 300 -quality 100 -thumbnail x1815 -background white -alpha remove "$file"[$page] "$path"/"$name"_$num.$ext
        else
            while [[ -e "$path"/"$name"_$num.$ext ]]; do
                (( num++ ))
            done
            echo "Creating thumbnail ..."
            convert -quiet -density 300 -quality 100 -thumbnail x1815 -background white -alpha remove "$file"[$page] "$path"/"$name"_$num.$ext
    fi

    while :
    do
        read -n 1 -s -p "Add watermark? [Y/n]" watermark
        case $watermark in
            ""|[yY] )
                echo ""
                echo "Adding watermark to thumbnail ..."
                convert -quiet "$path"/"$name"_$num.$ext "$mark" -gravity center -composite "$path"/"$name"_$num.$ext
                echo "DONE!"
                exit;
                ;;
            [nN] )
                echo ""
                echo "DONE!"
                exit;
                ;;
            * )
                echo ""
                echo "Use only 'y' or 'n' !"
        esac
    done
}

# start
echo ""
while :
do
    read -e -p "Path to PDF: " file
    if [[ -d "$file" ]]; then
        echo "'$file' is a directory"
        echo "Enter path to PDF File!"
    elif [[ -z "$file" ]]; then
            echo "Enter path to file!"
    elif [[ "$file" = /* ]]; then
        file=$(echo "$file" | tr -d "\\")
            break
        else
            echo "Enter FULL path!"
    fi
done

while :
do
    read -e -p "Page to be converted (leave blank for first): " page
    if [[ -n ${page//[0-9]/} ]]; then
        echo "Use numbers only!"
    elif [[ -z "$page" ]]; then
            page="0"
            break
        else
            break
    fi
done

while :
do
    read -e -p "Path to save: " path
    if [[ -f "$path" ]]; then
        echo "'$path' is file"
        echo "Enter path to save thumbnail into!"
    elif [[ -z "$path" ]]; then
            path='/path/to/your/folder'
            break
        else
            break
    fi
done

CONVERT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally find out, how to do that!

```
    # set functions
CONVERT()
{
    num=0
    name=$(basename "$file" .pdf | cut -d- -f1 | sed 's/.$//' | tr ' ' '-')
    ext="png"
    mark='/path/to/the/watermark.png'
    for page in ${pages[*]}
        do
            if [[ ! -e "$path"/"$name"_$num.$ext ]]; then
                echo "Creating thumbnail ..."
                convert -quiet -density 300 -quality 100 -thumbnail x1815 -background white -alpha remove "$file"[$page] "$path"/"$name"_$num.$ext
                while :
                do
                    read -n 1 -s -p "Add watermark? [Y/n]" watermark
                    case $watermark in
                        ""|[yY] )
                            echo ""
                            echo "Adding watermark to thumbnail ..."
                            convert -quiet "$path"/"$name"_$num.$ext "$mark" -gravity center -composite "$path"/"$name"_$num.$ext
                            echo "DONE!"
                            break
                            ;;
                        [nN] )
                            echo ""
                            echo "DONE!"
                            break
                            ;;
                        * )
                            echo ""
                            echo "Use only 'y' or 'n' !"
                    esac
                done
            else
                while [[ -e "$path"/"$name"_$num.$ext ]]; do
                    (( num++ ))
                done
                echo "Creating thumbnail ..."
                convert -quiet -density 300 -quality 100 -thumbnail x1815 -background white -alpha remove "$file"[$page] "$path"/"$name"_$num.$ext
                while :
                do
                    read -n 1 -s -p "Add watermark? [Y/n]" watermark
                    case $watermark in
                        ""|[yY] )
                            echo ""
                            echo "Adding watermark to thumbnail ..."
                            convert -quiet "$path"/"$name"_$num.$ext "$mark" -gravity center -composite "$path"/"$name"_$num.$ext
                            echo "DONE!"
                            break
                            ;;
                        [nN] )
                            echo ""
                            echo "DONE!"
                            break
                            ;;
                        * )
                            echo ""
                            echo "Use only 'y' or 'n' !"
                    esac
                done
            fi
        done
}

# start
echo ""
while :
do
    read -e -p "Path to PDF: " file
    if [[ -d "$file" ]]; then
        echo "'$file' is a directory"
        echo "Enter path to PDF File!"
    elif [[ -z "$file" ]]; then
            echo "Enter path to file!"
    elif [[ "$file" = /* ]]; then
        file=$(echo "$file" | tr -d "\\")
            break
        else
            echo "Enter FULL path!"
    fi
done

while :
do
    read -e -p "Page to be converted (leave blank for first): " -a pages
    if [[ -z "$pages" ]]; then
            pages="0"
            break
        else
            break
    fi
done

while :
do
    read -e -p "Path to save: " path
    if [[ -f "$path" ]]; then
        echo "'$path' is file"
        echo "Enter path to save thumbnail into!"
    elif [[ -z "$path" ]]; then
            path='/path/of/your/choice'
            break
        else
            break
    fi
done

CONVERT
```

It looks a bit "messy", but it works! If you find out, how to make the code "cleaner", please, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`read` has an `-a` option to read into an array:

```
$ read -r -p 'Enter page numbers: ' -a pages
Enter page numbers: 1 2 3 4 5
$ declare -p pages
declare -a pages=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5")
```

Comment: Thank you! And how to implement it to my "CONVERT" function?

Comment: @Strejda603 You can loop over the array with `for page in "${pages[@]}"; do echo "$page"; done`, where insteads of `echo "$page"` you do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

In Imagemagick, you can watermark and thumbnail several images or pages of one image in one command line if you are willing to use the same output name as the input name and have numerical indices appended. To do that you include a null: separator after the input and use -layers composite rather than just -composite to do the watermarking.

Input:

[image]

Here I use the special Imagemagick internal rose: image to watermark the second and third images in the animation (or a PDF file, if you want) and then thumbnail it by 50%. You can replace rose: with any proper image.suffix.

```
convert 3images.pdf[1,2] null: rose: -gravity center -compose over -layers composite -thumbnail 50% 3images_thumbs_%d.png
```

Resulting 2 image:

3images_thumbs_1.png

[image]

3images_thumbs_2.png

[image]